# Join operations on arrays

Tags: php, arrays

Is there any library which i can use to do mysql operations like leftjoin, rightjoin and join on 2 arrays in PHP. We cannot do cross DB joins. We get some data from our Database and some data from REST API from another.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds as though you need to use something like [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb397926.aspx)

One of the following libraries may help:

- [PHPLinq](http://phplinq.codeplex.com/)
- [phinq](http://code.google.com/p/phinq/)
- [Yalinqo](https://github.com/Athari/YaLinqo)
- [Linq for PHP](http://linqforphp.codeplex.com/)
- [plinq](http://plinq.codeplex.com/)

Comment: 1 source of data if from database and another is from API from other server. I need to merge data based on conditions and do sorting etc and then forma JSON and pass on to view.

Comment: Yes, you said in the question: so you retrieve the data from the database to an array, call the API and format that data to an array, then use LINQ to select with joins from your two arrays and generate the results array, which you can then format to json and return

Comment: Which is the best one to use. I need to be able to do a join on 2 arrays, sort, sum, group by. I am confused which one to use.